# "move_uploaded_file" function not working in SugarCRM logic hook

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am trying to move uploaded files to new location using SugarCRM's logic hook either `after_save` or `before_save`. But I am unable to do so. Kindly find my logic hook code:

```
class attachment
{
    public function attachment(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
    {       
        if(!empty($bean->filename_new))
        {               
            $upload_dir = $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['upload_dir'];

            $target_file = $upload_dir . basename($_FILES["filename_new_file"]["name"]);

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename_new_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("The file has been uploaded");
            }
            else
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when I print `$_FILES`, I am getting desired output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => twitter.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php5wBmgK
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 203
)
```

Now I have seen many posts, where they mentioned solution for this is to make sure the correct file permission and file ownership. I tried that, but didn't work out.

Lastly, to remove the possibility of issue with file permission or file ownership, I made one file upload script and run that script outside of CRM and that time `move_uploaded_file` function worked as it should.

But when I try to achieve the same with the use of logic hook, I am unable to get desired output. Kindly guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using **UNIX** please check **Permission** also.
Check this file   `Rootapp/include/upload_file.php` you will get different function related to file .
I use this to copy file.
And you want to change location of file where file saving then ,
If you look at your **config.php** file, you will see a line that looks like this.

```
'upload_dir' => 'upload/',
```

to copy a file i did like this,

```
 $bean->file_mime_type = $result->file_mime_type;
 $bean->filename = $result->filename;
 require_once('include/upload_file.php');
  $uploadFile = new UploadFile();
  $upoad_atachment =         
      $uploadFile->duplicate_file($result->id, $bean->id)
```

IN logic hook after save when i get email with attachment i copy that attachment and insert that files into my custom module.
Every image have some id , the image name uploaded with that id, so find that id , for email that attachment information save into notes module, In your case you find in your module. then get that information in your result and copy that in other module.

Comment: Hello @Amitesh, thanks for replying as I am bit stressed out here. I have checked permission, it was 755. Even I gave 777. But still no desirable result. About `upload_dir`, I have already mentioned that in my code above. And about `upload_file.php` file, I have checked that, but confused here on  how to use. If you have already achieve something, kindly share your code, it will be very helpful.

Comment: I added my code for copy email attachments. please upvote if you find helpful and accept if it is a solution.